# My merge sort algorithm is taking too long for large file input?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

well it's not exactly a merge sort, the algorithm counts the number on inversions in an array using merge sort (basically I just added one simple line)
it takes 2.415 seconds to read and merge sort 100,000 distinct integers from a text file  while others who solved the same problem (on coursera.com) said it took them less than 0.5 seconds

here's my code, what went wrong? file reading maybe? thanks

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int a,b,i,j,n,x,k;
int t[100000]={0};
long long int s=0;

void merge(int a, int mid, int b)
     {
         i=a;
        j=mid+1;
        k=a;
        int v[100000]={0};
        while(i<=mid && j<= b)
        {
            if (t[i]<t[j])
                {v[k]=t[i];
                 i++;
                }
            else
            {v[k]=t[j];
             j++;
              s+=mid-i+1; //this line here counts the inversions
             }
           k++;
        }
       while(i<=mid)
        {v[k]=t[i];
         i++; k++;}

        while(j<=b)
        {v[k]=t[j];
         j++; k++;}

      for (i=a;i<k;i++)
         t[i]=v[i];
    }


void mergeSort(int a, int b)
    {
        if(a<b)
        {
           int mid=(a+b)/2;
            mergeSort(a,mid);
            mergeSort(mid+1,b);
            merge(a,mid,b);
        }
    }


int main(){
  ifstream fin("C:\\Users\\ASUS\\Desktop\\coursera.txt");
    n=100000;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        fin>>t[i];

    mergeSort(0,n-1);

     cout<<endl<<s;

}
```

Comment: Post it in [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) please.

Comment: How long does it take to do everything *but* mergeSort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I could see is that in merge function, you allocate too much space, and the copy back also take quite O(N), which make the total copy time O(N * N) instead of O(N*Log(N)). Simple change to merge function could be like:

```
void merge(int a, int mid, int b)
{
    i = a;
    j = mid + 1;
    k = 0;
    int* v = new int[b - a + 1];
    while (i <= mid && j <= b)
    {
        if (t[i]<t[j])
        {
            v[k] = t[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            v[k] = t[j];
            j++;
            s += mid - i + 1; //this line here counts the inversions
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    {
        v[k] = t[i];
        i++; k++;
    }

    while (j <= b)
    {
        v[k] = t[j];
        j++; k++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i<k; i++)
        t[a+i] = v[i];

    delete[] v;
    v = NULL;
}
```